# How to highlight dates in coldFusion that are working days (Mon-Fri)

Tags: coldfusion

I have an if statement that currently highlights rows 3 different colours depending on how greater they are to the current date, for example if date received was last Friday then it would be red. What I'm trying to work out is how to change it so that it's only been 2 working days since and should be highlighted yellow.

This is my current statement...

```
 <cfif  #ROUTING_NAME# eq 'Inspection Required' and #INSPECTION_STATUS# eq 'NOT INSPECTED'>
    <cfif #DAYS_RECEIVED# gt 3 >
        <td  title = 'Part'  width="200" bgcolor="ff3333" align="center" >#PART#</td>
    <cfelseif  #DAYS_RECEIVED#  gt 1  and #DAYS_RECEIVED# lte 3 >
        <td  title = 'Part'  width="200" bgcolor="FFFF00" align="center" >#PART#</td>
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Are stat holidays relevant?

Comment: These are two different things 1) Highlight Mon-Fri  ... OR ... 2) determine if "it's only been 2 working days since (some date)". Which one are you trying to do?

Comment: It looks like it just needs the ifs and elses properly nested. For every start of and if it needs to be ended. You might want to set the color in a `<cfscript>` block if that style of coding is easier for you to understand.